# Angular2 NgRouter with shared parent component

Tags: angular

I have the following components in my **angular 2 typescript application**:

- AppComponent
- ProjectComponent

  - ProjectListComponent
  - ProjectNewComponent

I have a simple layout, which should be the same on **all** pages, so I put the following **html code** for the main component:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1><a routerLink="/">Home</a>
<hr />
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

As far as I understand, the router injects its content in the `<router-outlet>`. Now I wanted to create a nested project component. For simplicity, the project component should consist of three parts. One parent component, which only holds the headline and a container and two child components which are nested in the parent component.

My `app.routing.ts` looks as follows:

```
const appRoutes : Routes = [
    {
        path: 'project',
        component: ProjectComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'id/:id', component: ProjectEditComponent },
            { path: 'new', component: ProjectNewComponent }
        ]
    }
];
```

My question is: How must the `Project` component and the `ProjectList` component look like?

So far I have `project.html`:

```
<h3>Projects</h3>
<hr />
<project-list></project-list>
<project-new></project-new>
```

My goal is something like, whenever I call `ProjectListComponent` or `ProjectNewComponent`:

```
<h3>Projects</h3>
<hr />
<div>
    <project-current-component></project-current-component>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that? The advantage of this would be that I don't have to rewrite any html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understand what you want are trying to achieve, your Projects component should also include a router outlet (in angular2 RC5 that i am working with lately, nesting router outlets is allowed).

**AppComponent** would be something like:

```
<h1>This is the app component title</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**ProjectComponent** would be :

```
<h3>Projects</h3>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And the **child** components of ProjectsComponent would be :

```
<h5>Child components area</h5> 
<div>
<!-- place whatever code you have inside here -->   
     <project-current-component></project-current-component>
</dir>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do. I also found this example online: https://plnkr.co/edit/QlMe6pMINxJGTdA3xm0B?p=preview

Comment: Note however that this example uses an older version. I would suggest you to switch to rc5 since it is, according to what the angular team says, very close to what the official 2.0.0 release will be.